# How to make this do_deploy machine overrides work?

Tags: overriding, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm trying to understand why the below code doesn't work. From `bitbake -e` it would seem that task `do_deploy` is empty. I'm using Yocto gatesgarth.

```
addtask deploy after do_install before do_build

do_deploy_MACHINE-A () {
    bbinfo "Doing something for machine A"
}

do_deploy_MACHINE-B () {
    bbinfo "Doing something for machine B"
}
```

Comment: Is your machine really called something with "_" in the name? That is an unfortunate choice of character if so.

Comment: @RichardPurdie, My bad, I have edited the question. We use machine name with "-" in between, not "_".

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding:

```
do_xyz() {
    echo 1
}

do_xyz:qemux86-64() {
    echo 2
}
```

to the bash.inc file, then running "bitbake-getvar -r bash do_xyz" with MACHINE = "qemux86-64" I see:

```
# line: 133, file: /xxx/meta/recipes-extended/bash/bash.inc
do_xyz() {
    echo 2
}
```

This is with master where bitbake-getvar is available and overrides use the ":" character. Your branch may vary but it does appear to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on Yocto gatesgarth (3.2.1). Not sure which one you have. I never saw an override using `:` character like this though. And thank you also for `-r` switch.

Comment: With gatesgarth you would use "_" for overrides, ":" is a recent change in master/honister. bitbake-getvar will not be available in gatesgarth either so use bitbake -e.